# "Back to Top" within Iframe, cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe and within that iframe I have a "Back to Top" button that takes the user back to the top of the iframe. The button works sporadically in IE but doesn't work at all on Firefox and Google Chrome. The code that the button uses is below:

```
<input type="button" class="submit_long" onClick="window.location='#';
document.getElementById('tablecon').scrollTop = 0; window.scrollTo = (0,0);"
value="Back To Top" accesskey="T" tabindex="9999" name="button4">
```

The iframe's location is orders.example.com and the parent is located on example.com. Would this fall under the same domain issue? If this is the same domain issue why is it working in IE and not Firefox? Are there any workarounds? I don't need it to go to the top of the parent just the top of the iframe.

I'm open to any suggestions except one that requires the use of multiple helper files.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it a link and style it like a button:

```
<a href="#" class="some-class-to-make-it-look-like-a-button">Back to Top</a>
```

That way you rely less on inline JavaScript.

Comment: This works on Firefox and Chrome but not IE. When the link is clicked in IE the whole page reloads which is undesirable because it reloads the contents of the Iframe.